# How do I save the below query in a permanent table?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *from DATA_2018
UNION
SELECT * from DATA_2019
UNION 
SELECT * from DATA_2020
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here, please don't tag spam. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products, and SSMS is specifically an IDE for SQL Server; it doesn't work with MySQL.

Comment: Side notes: `UNION` is unlikely to be performant nor the correct choice here. Do you *really* have duplicate rows for different years? If you do, do you *really* want to "merge" them into a single row? I suspect you want `UNION ALL` here. Your design, however, is flawed; don't store a year's data in different table, store it all in one table and have a column called `year` (or similar). Hopefully the reason you've posted this question is so you can fix said said.

Comment: You probably want to create a view, then just add `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATA AS` to the top of your statement provided that your DBMS is MySQL (Syntax of SQL Server is different for creating a view), and just use this query : `SELECT * FROM DATA`. Btw, don't neglect to check out the `Side notes` within the comment above while creating the view.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean save the *results* of the query.

You have tagged MySQL: You simply prefix with a normal *insert* statement.

Given an existing table with identical schema to store the results

```
insert into <target table>
select * from <your same query>
```

[See the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

You have also tagged SQL Server which supports `into` :

```
SELECT * into <target table name> 
from DATA_2018
UNION
SELECT * from DATA_2019
UNION 
SELECT * from DATA_2020
```

Comment: Thank you so much